# Stripe: Sending Invoice 7 Days before subscription ends

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments, payment

I just wanted to know is there any way that we can generate a invoice in Stripe's monthly subscription 7 days before the subscription ends. I did lots of searches on web but couldn't find any solutions. Is there any event that it throws when a subscription ends 7 days before ?
I would really appreciate your help!

I would expect it to generate a invoice 7 days before the expiration or cancellation of subscription

Comment: There can be ways to force an Invoice (e.g. calling https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle#api-now at the 7 day-before date) , but I think you would need to clearly lay out what you want to happen, how much the early Invoice should be for, what should happen to the Invoice that would have happened at the original date and so on, giving clear examples

Answer (score 0):

Stripe only 'generates' the Invoice object when the billing date triggers. There is no way to generate an upcoming Invoice, other than by resetting this date to now.

What you can do is to preview the upcoming Invoice, using the `invoice.upcoming` API. This still won't give you any document - Invoice pdfs are only generated once the Invoice is created and finalized.
https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/upcoming

Note that you can also set an `invoice.upcoming` event to trigger some days before the Invoice is created from your Settings:
https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/billing/automatic
This is for every Invoice though - not just the last Invoice.

Speaking of last Invoice - are you sure there would be one?
There is typically no Invoice at Subscription cancellation time - unless your Price is metered (=>billing in arrears) or the Customer has pending invoice items and the Subscription was set to cancel in a very [specific way](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/cancel).